# How to add imagepath inside array one by one in iphone

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I am new to iPhone programming. How do I add an `NSString` to an `NSArray`. I have thumbnail images. If I click on any one of the images I want to store imagepath in the `NSArray`. Same if I click on the same image I want to remove the imagepath from `NSArray`. (like select and deselect) Can anybody tell me how I can do this, what is the logic for that? Till now I have been doing

```
- (void)click
{

   NSLog(@"%@",_fullsizeUrl);
   array =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   [array addObject:_fullsizeUrl];         
   NSLog(@"%@",array);

}
```

In above code `_fullsizeUrl` is imagepath I am storing this in an `NSMutableArray`. The problem is if select any one image means Ii getting image path that is storing in `NSArray`. But if I select any other images it's storing the latest one previous one is removing. Can any body tell me how to do this
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your "previous one is removing" because you are reallocating your `NSMutableArray` everytime you tap the thumbnail. Allocate the array outside the click method.

```
-(void)click
{
    if ([yourAry containsObject:yourObject])
    {
        [yourAry removeObject:yourObject];
    }
    else{
        [yourAry addObject:yourObject];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
array =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[array addObject:_fullsizeUrl];
```

You are creating a new array every time `click` is called. At the end of the method, the array has no strong references (assuming ARC, otherwise you are leaking memory) and gets deallocated.

Make your `NSMutableArray` a property on your class and then `click` should look like this:

```
- (void)click
{
    if ([self.myArray containsObject:self.fullSizeUrl]) {
        [self.myArray removeObject:self.fullSizeUrl];
    } else {
        [self.myArray addObject:self.fullSizeUrl];
    }
}
```

If you are only storing unique strings in your array you could consider using `NSMutableSet` instead.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this method and use one int variable i and increase ever time +1.

```
- (void)insertObject:(id)anObject atIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
```